# Convert a txt document to a list to a list starting with [[, instead of ['[

Tags: python, txt, tolist

I have a .txt document with this type of text:

[(“Vazhdo”,”verb”),(“të”,”particle”),(“ecësh”,”verb”),(“!”,”excl.”)]

(which represents a sentence and the Parts of Speech tags for each word)

I want to have a list of list in python, like this:

[[(“Vazhdo”,”verb”),(“të”,”particle”),(“ecësh”,”verb”),(“!”,”excl.”)]]

But I obtain this:

['[(“Vazhdo”,”verb”),(“të”,”particle”),(“ecësh”,”verb”),(“!”,”excl.”)]\n']

The code I'm using is:

```
import io
f=io.open("test.txt", mode="r", encoding="utf-8-sig")
f_list = list(f)
```

How can I avoid the ['[ .... ]\n']  ?

Thank you!

Comment: The best solution here might to be to modify whatever *produces* that file to write, for example, proper JSON instead. Obviously, that is not always possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it looks like you can just do

```
import json
data = json.load(open('test.txt'))
```

this answer was **wrong** sorry... `[("word","QQ")]` is **NOT** valid json as json does not support tuples

instead you should be able to do

```
import ast
data = ast.literal_eval(io.open("test.txt", mode="r", encoding="utf-8-sig").read())
```

here is my version

```
import io,ast,requests

#text file available at
text_url = "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/joranbeasley/a50d940d9ac47e8458f027d3cc88e236/raw/3a65169d30e653e085284de16b1ee715f3596c95/example.txt"
with open("example.txt","wb") as f:
    # download and save textfile
    f.write(requests.get(text_url).content)

data = ast.literal_eval(io.open('example.txt',encoding='utf8').read())
print(data)
print(data[0])
print(data[0][0])
```

results in

```
[('Vazhdo', 'verb'), ('të', 'particle'), ('ecësh', 'verb'), ('!', 'excl.')]
('Vazhdo', 'verb')
Vazhdo
```

Comment: I tried it, but I receive this error because of the encoding:


UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 16: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: you i guess need `io.open("test.txt", mode="r", encoding="utf-8-sig")` instead of just open :/

Comment: It gives this error after adding it:

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 2 (char 1)

Comment: @BrikenaLiko yeah ... oops it was my bad (see answer edit)

Comment: What does it gives to your computer, if you  replicate the txt file with the text above?
Because , if it works for you, I don't know what I'm doing wrong, I just copy-pasted and I read the error: 
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: can you post your actual text file ... i did copy and paste and it worked fine... but it is probably encoding issues that dont manifest with copy and paste ... . if it actually has those funny quotes that might be problematic (alot of times those are introduced in copy paste errors) ... do you have any ability to change how the file is generated just slightly ... this seems like someone was trying to write json....but they did it wrong

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241849/discussion-between-brikena-liko-and-joran-beasley).

Answer (score 1):

`io.open()` reads the file as a list of strings so you'll need to `eval`uate each line of the `.txt` file to get a list of lists instead of your list of strings.

Here's how you can accomplish that:

```
temp = ['[("Vazhdo","verb"),("të","particle"),("ecësh","verb"),("!","excl.")]\n']
f_list = []
for i in temp:
  f_list.append(eval(i.strip()))

print(f_list)

#[[('Vazhdo', 'verb'), ('të', 'particle'), ('ecësh', 'verb'), ('!', 'excl.')]]


#OR

f_list = [eval(lst.strip()) for lst in f_list]
```

Comment: SyntaxError: invalid character '“' (U+201C)

Comment: Yeah that's a problem with the double-quote type itself, most probably the file encoding is something else than UTF-8. 

You can try fixing it by replacing all `“` with normal `"` / `'`, worked for me  

Comment: You were so right!
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

you can delete a blank line with strip method, like:

```
f_list[0] = f_list[0].rstrip()
```

Comment: I tried it, it gives me the same beginning again:

['[(“Vazhdo”,

Comment: when I try it:
`f_list = ['[(“Vazhdo”,”verb”),(“të”,”particle”),(“ecësh”,”verb”),(“!”,”excl.”)]\n']

print ('\n' in f_list[0])

f_list[0] = f_list[0].rstrip()

print ('\n' in f_list[0])`

the first output is True so there is a blank line
but after strip
the output is false
so there is no blank line and that was deleted